# Quickly compute `dot(a(n:end), b(1:end-n))`

Tags: algorithm, matlab, vector, convolution, numerical-methods

Suppose we have two, one dimensional arrays of values `a` and `b` which both have length `N`. I want to create a new array `c` such that `c(n)=dot(a(n:N), b(1:N-n+1))` I can of course do this using a simple loop:

```
for n=1:N
    c(n)=dot(a(n:N), b(1:N-n+1));
end
```

but given that this is such a simple operation which resembles a convolution I was wondering if there isn't a more efficient method to do this (using Matlab).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A solution using 1D convolution `conv`:

```
out = conv(a, flip(b));
c = out(ceil(numel(out)/2):end);
```

In `conv` the first vector is multiplied by the reversed version of the second vector so we need to compute the convolution of `a` and the flipped `b` and trim the unnecessary part.

Answer (score 5):

This is an interesting problem!

I am going to assume that `a` and `b` are column vectors of the same length. Let us consider a simple example:

```matlab
a = [9;10;2;10;7];
b = [1;3;6;10;10];
% yields:
c = [221;146;74;31;7];
```

Now let's see what happens when we compute the convolution of these vectors:

```matlab
>> conv(a,b)
ans =
     9
    37
    86
   166
   239
   201
   162
   170
    70

>> conv2(a, b.')
ans =
     9    27    54    90    90
    10    30    60   100   100
     2     6    12    20    20
    10    30    60   100   100
     7    21    42    70    70
```

We notice that `c` is the sum of elements along the lower diagonals of the result of `conv2`. To show it clearer we'll transpose to get the diagonals in the same order as values in `c`:

```matlab
>> triu(conv2(a.', b))
ans =
     9    10     2    10     7
     0    30     6    30    21
     0     0    12    60    42
     0     0     0   100    70
     0     0     0     0    70
```

So now it becomes a question of summing the diagonals of a matrix, which is [a more common problem](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/326858-sum-over-all-diagonals-in-lower-matrix) with existing solution, for example this one by Andrei Bobrov:

```matlab
C = conv2(a.', b);
p = sum( spdiags(C, 0:size(C,2)-1) ).'; % This gives the same result as the loop.
```

Comment: How about performance wise? Can you add a small timing experiment?

Comment: I timed the solution for `N=10^4`, `a=1:N` and `b=1:N`. I then did:

tic
C = conv2(a.', b);
p1 = sum( spdiags(C, 0:size(C,2)-1) ).';
toc

and

tic
for n=1:N
    p2(i)=dot(a(n:end), b(1:end-n+1));
end
toc

and the first method (your solution I believe) took 2 seconds while the other took 0.2 seconds.. I like the solution it looks neat but might not be very efficient?

Comment: @Darkwizie do note that `tic/toc` measures actual wall-clock time, and might be inaccurate for performance tests. Use [`timeit()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) instead

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if a simple loop is faster for large `N`, since it doesn't involve convolutions and creating large matrices (vs your original 1D vectors)... loops aren't inherently slow in MATLAB, and it's clear what's going on

Comment: Thank you for the hint of using timeit(), it yields similar timings.

Comment: Note that the benchmark in the linked post (on MATLAB Answers) suggests that a loops is not bad at all...